# Iterator function not working on internal variable

Tags: kotlin

I'm completing Kotlin Koans's [For loop](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Conventions/For%20loop/Task.kt) exercise and am wondering why:

```
class DateRange(val start: MyDate, val end: MyDate) : Iterable<MyDate> {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<MyDate> = DateIterator(this)
}

class DateIterator(val daterange: DateRange) : Iterator<MyDate> {
    var currentDay: MyDate = daterange.start
    override fun hasNext(): Boolean = currentDay.next() <= daterange.end

    override fun next(): MyDate {
        val result = currentDay
        currentDay = currentDay.nextDay()
        return result

    }
}
```

I'm receiving an `Unresolved reference: next` on `currentDay()`.

I'm aware the answer to this question is the exact same code without `next()`, but am wondering why it doesn't work - considering `currentDay` is a `MyDate` object and `next()` returns a `MyDate`.

Any idea why?

Comment: Did you define `next()` method in `MyDate` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> considering `currentDay` is a `MyDate` object and `next()` returns a `MyDate`

But there is no method `next()` on the `MyDate` class (which is what the error message tries to say). So `currentDay.next()` will not compile.

There is only `next()` on the `DateIterator` class (but of course you don't want to call that as it would have the side-effect of advancing the iterator).

You must have meant to call `currentDay.nextDay()` instead.